# How can I make cron jobs to POST to a url through PHP scripts?

Tags: php, cron

I am not sure how I can assign cron jobs through PHP script AND have that cron job POST to a PHP script. Any ideas? Also, what would I need to tell my webhost people? usually If i want to allow one or more PHP script to have write access to a csv or textfile I ask them to allow that csv or textfile to have apache writes. For this cron PHP script what would I need to ask them?

Comment: Look into cURL and what it can do

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you'd want to use cURL - it should be installed as an extension for your php.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php has all the options for making a web request - browse through them at your leisure.

http://www.ipragmatech.com/post-form-data-java-php-curl.html has a quick example for doing so.